# Mongodb multi update, only updates a single document in mongo-shell

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I am learning mongodb and am trying to perform a simple multi documents update with the {$multi: true} option, but it only updates a single document.

```
> db.users.update({'color': 'black'}, {$set: {'title': 'blackers'}}, {$multi: true});

WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })

> db.users.find({'color': 'black'});

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5562312f061fa19e6cebc7e4"), "color" : "black", "hobby" : [ "dancing", "breaking", "drawing", "praying", "smiling" ], "name" : "john", "schools" : [ "mlimwa", "martin", "ignatus", "eget", "jubilee", "canon" ], "title" : "blackers" }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5564057bb0f557f0c0589e66"), "color" : [ "black" ], "name" : "demo" }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("556424fc1dd78ab02dd2918f"), "color" : "black", "name" : "tola" }

>db.version()
3.0.3
```

Please help am really stuck..

Comment: problem is that your documents contains only one documents which contains `title` field and having value `blackers` , and your update query update same field value if you changed `blackers to blackers1` it update only one documents, if you want to set title write as `update({'color': 'black'}, {$set: {'title': 'blackers122'}},true,true)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is not `$multi`, write only `{multi:true}`

```
db.users.update({'color': 'black'}, {$set: {'title': 'blackers'}}, {multi: true});
```

refer the documentation here, for further help, regarding upsert, or writeconcern params
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/

Comment: hhaha.. thank you very much, I had that error in upsert and multi and couldn't turn my eye right for hours..
Cheers..